# GetUniformLocation always -1 / Projectionmatrix error

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I wanted to start developing an opengl basic game. After some coding i ran into an error.
I wanted to add a projection matrix and after I created it, the rendered image went white and even the transformation matrix didn't work correctly.
I tested the location IDs with `GL.GetUniformLocation(Variable Names)` and both of them were `-1`.

The way I add the projection matrix:

```
projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)(Math.PI / 180) * FOV, aspectRatio, NEAR_PLANE, FAR_PLANE);
```

The way I add the transformation matrix:

```
Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(rx)) * Matrix4.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(ry)) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(rz));
Matrix4 translationsMatrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(translation);
Matrix4 scaleMatrix = Matrix4.CreateScale(scale);
matrix *= scaleMatrix;
matrix *= translationsMatrix;
```

This(the transformation matrix) works fine by it's own.

And here is my renderer class:

```
TexturedModel texturedModel = entity.Model;
RawModel model = texturedModel.Model;
GL.BindVertexArray(model.VaoID);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
Matrix4 transformationMatrix = Maths.CreateTransformationMatrix(entity.Position, entity.RotationX, entity.RotationY, entity.RotationZ, entity.Scale);
shader.LoadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);
GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texturedModel.Texture.ID);
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, model.VertexCount, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(1);
GL.BindVertexArray(0);
```

Why does it behave like this and how can I "fix" it?

**EDIT**

Here are my shader codes. (I have forgotten them previously)

VertexShader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
unfiorm mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main(void){

gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

}
```

Abstract Shader Class:

```
  abstract class ShaderProgram
{
    private int programID;
    private int vertexShaderID;
    private int fragmentShaderID;

    public ShaderProgram(string vertexShaderFile, string fragmentShaderFile)
    {
        vertexShaderID = LoadShader(vertexShaderFile, ShaderType.VertexShader);
        fragmentShaderID = LoadShader(fragmentShaderFile, ShaderType.FragmentShader);

        programID = GL.CreateProgram();
        GL.AttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
        GL.AttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
        BindAttributes();
        GL.LinkProgram(programID);
        GL.ValidateProgram(programID);
        GetAllUniformLocations();
    }

    protected abstract void GetAllUniformLocations();

    protected int GetUniformLocation(string uniformName)
    {
        return GL.GetUniformLocation(programID, uniformName);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        GL.UseProgram(programID);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        GL.UseProgram(0);
    }

    public void CleanUp()
    {
        Stop();
        GL.DetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
        GL.DetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
        GL.DeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
        GL.DeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
        GL.DeleteProgram(programID);
    }

    protected abstract void BindAttributes();

    protected void BindAttribute(int attribute, string variableName)
    {
        GL.BindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, variableName);
    }

    protected void LoadFloat(int location, float value)
    {
        GL.Uniform1(location, value);
    }

    protected void LoadVector(int location, Vector3 vector)
    {
        GL.Uniform3(location, vector);
    }

    protected void LoadBoolean(int location, bool value)
    {
        GL.Uniform1(location, value ? 1 : 0);
    }

    protected void LoadMatrix(int location, Matrix4 matrix)
    {
       GL.UniformMatrix4(location, false, ref matrix);
    }

    private static int LoadShader(String file, ShaderType type)
    {
        string shaderSource = File.ReadAllText(file);
        int shaderID = GL.CreateShader(type);
        GL.ShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
        GL.CompileShader(shaderID);

        return shaderID;
    }
}
```

Static Shader:

```
class StaticShader : ShaderProgram
{
    private static string vertexFile = "f/shaders/vertexShader.txt";
    private static string fragmentFile = "f/shaders/fragmentShader.txt";

    private int location_transformationMatrix;
    private int location_projectionMatrix;

    public StaticShader()
        : base(vertexFile, fragmentFile)
    {

    }

    protected override void BindAttributes()
    {
        base.BindAttribute(0, "position");
        base.BindAttribute(1, "textureCoords");
    }

    protected override void GetAllUniformLocations()
    {
        location_transformationMatrix = base.GetUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");
        location_projectionMatrix = base.GetUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
    }

    public void LoadTransformationMatrix(Matrix4 matrix)
    {
        base.LoadMatrix(location_transformationMatrix, matrix);
    }

    public void LoadProjectionMatrix(Matrix4 projection)
    {
        base.LoadMatrix(location_projectionMatrix, projection);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the shader code?

Comment: I have edited it in.

Comment: You should definitively add checks for detecting compilation and linking errors.

Comment: Found it...I misspelled the word "uniform", next time I'll check my code multiple times. Thanks.